# jquery passing this to variable function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, anonymous-function

I'm trying to make my own image rotator that will work if there is multiple image rotators on the screen. Here is what I have got so far:

```
// jQuery plugin to make image containers rotate.
(function($){

    // Swap text with title attribute
    $.fn.scWFWImageRotator = function() {

        var rotatorTimeSwap = 6000;

        $(this).find("img").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).find("img:first-child").addClass("selected");

        var rotatorImageChangeFunc = function(item) {
            var rotatorImages = $(item).children("img");
            var imgSelected = $(item).children("img.selected");
            var rotatorImgCount = rotatorImages.length;
            var rotatorCurImage = $(imgSelected).index(rotatorImages);
            alert(item);
        }

        return this.each(function() {

            var rotatorTimer;
            var $this  = $(this);
            var func = $.proxy( rotatorImageChangeFunc, $this );

            rotatorTimer = setInterval(func, rotatorTimeSwap);

            $this.hover(
                function() { rotatorTimer = clearInterval(rotatorTimer); },
                function() { rotatorTimer = setInterval(func, rotatorTimeSwap); }
            );

        });

    };

})(jQuery);
```

Problem is: `rotatorImageChangeFunc = function(item) {` item is not getting passed to the function. So inside that function I'm getting undefined for item. Why is this the case and how do I put it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context parameter you pass to [`proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) is passed to the function as `this`, not as an argument. Just change `item` to `this`.

---

Side note: In your main function, you have a couple of `$(this).find(...)`s. The `this` that plug-in functions sees is *already* a jQuert object (which is why your `this.each(...)` below works), no need to call `$()` on it again. Just `this.find(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

`$.proxy` only sets `this` for the wrapped function - it doesn't do anything with function parameters.

`setInterval()` will call your proxyed function with no parameters and therefore so will the original - `item` will be undefined.

To fix, remove `item` from the function's declaration, and do:

```
var item = this;
```

in the first line of the function.

[or rename all references to `item` with `this`].

Answer (score -1):

You have not defined the variable item anaywhere.